# bad magic number on decrypt

Tags: openssl

In April I encrypted a file using the command

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:<passwordfile> < infile > outfil
```

Now I want to decrypt it with

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:<passwordfile> -in outfil -out infile2
```

but I get bad magic number.

A file encrypted yesterday with the same parameters decrypts ok.

What could have happened? and is there anyway I can retrieve this archived file?

Answer (score 7):

If you encrypted with OpenSSL <=1.0.2 and you are decrypting with OpenSSL 1.1.0 then it is probably this:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3

The default hash used to generate the key from the password changed between 1.0.2 and 1.1.0. Try adding `-md md5` onto your decryption command.

Comment: thanks I was afraid it might be something like this  We are in an unusual situtaion wanting to restore something this old. I will give this a try

Comment: A mismatch in defaulted pbe-hash (or specifying the wrong hash or just the wrong password) will cause garbage decrypt which for a CBC-mode cipher (as here) will almost always be detected as 06065064 'bad decrypt' -- but not 'bad magic number'. Only a damaged file, or one encrypted with `-nosalt` or a _really_ ancient OpenSSL (before 0.9.6 at most) does that.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness: encrypting with **-a** params ( *Perform base64 encoding/decoding (alias -base64)* ) and decrypting without it, bad magic number given.

Comment: This is the key! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The general cause for this error is that the key computed by OpenSSL from the password is wrong, meaning not the same as the key that encrypted the data.

One reason when this error can show up, in a different situation than the original question, is if you are encrypting using another tool than OpenSSL, for example encrypting in Java, and decrypting using SSL.

See solution here for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610761/aes-simple-encrypt-in-java-decrypt-with-openssl/55884564#55884564

Answer (score 2):

The command below gave me pain:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in hotmama.tar.bz2.enc -out hotmama.tar.bz2
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
bad magic number
```

And the below command solved it, and gave me pleasure:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in hotmama.tar.bz2.enc -out hotmama.tar.bz2
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
```

Comment: In the second command, you are not decrypting (`-d`) ...