# Decrypt old openssl data

Tags: git, openssl

I have a git repo encrypted with `openssl`. I have moved the repo to a new host. The original host was using:

```
» openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016
```

The current host is using:

```
» openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

These are my filters for the `git` repo:

```
[filter "openssl"]
    smudge = ~/.gitencrypt/SALT-20131126-01/smudge_filter_openssl
    clean = ~/.gitencrypt/SALT-20131126-01/clean_filter_openssl
[diff "openssl"]
    textconv = ~/.gitencrypt/SALT-20131126-01/diff_filter_openssl
```

The encoding filter:

```
» cat ~/.gitencrypt/SALT-20131126-01/clean_filter_openssl
#!/bin/bash

# 24 or less hex characters
SALT_FIXED=mysalt
PASS_FIXED=mypass

openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-ecb -S $SALT_FIXED -k $PASS_FIXED
```

The decoding filter:

```
» cat ~/.gitencrypt/SALT-20131126-01/diff_filter_openssl
#!/bin/bash

# No salt is needed for decryption.
PASS_FIXED=mypass
# Error messages are redirect to /dev/null.
openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-256-ecb -k $PASS_FIXED -in "$1" 2> /dev/null || cat "$1"
```

I [have read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403314/bad-magic-number-on-decrypt#) that there are changes regarding the default hash used by OpenSSL. I have tried to force the old hash:

```
» git show HEAD~1:myfile > /tmp/xxx
» openssl enc -d -md md5 -base64 -aes-256-ecb -k mypass -in /tmp/xxx
```

But still gives me problems:

```
error reading input file
```

What else could I try?

Comment: Can you downgrade the openssl package temporarily? (I know it's not solution, but just workaround to get to data)

Comment: @JaroslavKucera thanks, but found the solution. If my analisys is correct, the `git show` command above was already applying a filter, so running the `openssl` command manually was working on already decrypted data, thus failing. The solution is just to update the filter scripts with the `-d -md md5` flags.

Comment: Good, make it answer then :-)